# OpenLayers: Performance on satellite hybrid map (raster tiles, vector tiles, vector labels)

Tags: javascript, openlayers, vector-tiles, vector-layer, xyz-tiles

I've got a map with three kinds of layers, each of which serving a somewhat different function:

- `TileLayer`: raster tiled map from an XYZ source (as .png) to show photographs in the background
- `VectorTileLayer`: vector tiled map from an MVT source (as .pbf) to show polygon boundaries and enable interaction with features
- `VectorLayer`: text labels of different size, loaded from a database, converted to JSON, and styled client-side

It's supposed to work like a labeled satellite map with photographs in the background and clickable district boundaries labeled with a text.

However, I run into several performance problems here:

- Vector tiles load (or render) much slower than I expected and they delay loading of the raster tiles. When running the application locally without vector tiles, raster tiles will load extremely fast despite having a much larger file size in general (this is of course different when using a remote server). With vector tiles activated, even locally, they will show up only after the vector tiles have been loaded.
- Vector labels will load fast but panning seems to be much slower when they're activated, also locally.

I wonder what's the bottleneck here: Is it just polygon counts for vector tiles and animation time for labels or could there be something more to it? Can I do anything about it without changing the data?

Here's some code to illustrate the structure:

```js
// RASTER TILE LAYER
     var raster_tiles = new TileLayer({
        source: new XYZ({
          // ...
        }),
        // ...
        zIndex: 1
      });
    
// VECTOR TILE LAYER 
    var vector_tiles = new VectorTileLayer({
              source: new VectorTileSource({
                format: new MVT(),
                // ...
          }),
          zIndex: 2,
          renderMode: 'hybrid'
          // ...
    });
 
// VECTOR LAYER FOR LABELS
    var vector_lbl = new VectorLayer({
        updateWhileAnimating: true,         // smooth animation on zoom
        updateWhileInteracting: false,      // no update needed on pan
        source: new Vector({                   
           format: new GeoJSON(),
           // ...
        }),
        style: styleFunction,
        zIndex: 3
    });

// MAP    
var map = new Map({
    target: 'map',
    //...
    loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
    loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,
    layers: [
        raster_tiles,
        vector_tiles,
        vector_lbl,
    ]
});
```

Comment: I found something very strange going on: For both, vector/raster tile sources, I'm using the```tileUrlFunction``` attribute (takes ```tileCoordinate``` for each tile, returns  custom URL). Now when I add ```console.log("z:", tileCoordinate[0], "x:", tileCoordinate[1], "y:", tileCoordinate[2]);``` there, I can check the coords for each tile request. For raster tiles it looks normal, loading the current extent. However for vector tiles, they seem to be requested multiple times and at additional zoom levels. Might this be the key to their bad performance— and what could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Indeed, some of the performance issues (for vector tiles) seem to be related to what might be a bug in OpenLayers, leading to excess requests of vector tiles in the ``tileUrlFunction``. See [here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/12136) for the bug report. Still, if anyone has got further ideas to improve the overall performance, it would be much appreciated.